# I create custom HTML email signature to OUTLOOK 365 - doesnt working

Tags: html, email, outlook, html-email, email-client

I create a custom email HTML signature for my outlook profile but when I add to my signatures and rewrite the file from HTML to HTM, this signature doesn't work. When I open signature in OUTLOOK for edit it is an empty editor page.

Can you write a comment and advise me on this problem?

I created this email signature the first time and I don't know where I have mistaken.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
            <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
            <o:AllowPNG/>
            <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
            </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
        </xml><![endif]-->
    <style media="screen" type="text/css">
        .arial {
            font-family: Arial;
        }

        .container {
            max-width: 650px;
        }

        .font-14 {
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .font-12 {
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        .font-10 {
            font-size: 10px;
        }

        .bold {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .i-block {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .blue {
            color: rgb(24, 71, 132);
        }

        .image {
            max-width: 600px;
            height: auto;
        }

        .profile {
            width: 90px;
            height: 90px;
            object-fit: cover;
            object-position: center top;
        }

        .fa {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .height-space {
            height: 20px;
        }

        .tr-height {
            height: 20px;
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
            .image {
                width: 450px;
            }

            .container {
                max-width: 450px;
            }

            .profile {
                max-width: 70px;
                max-height: 70px;
            }

            .fa {
                display: none;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
            .height-space {
                height: 10px;
            }

            .tr-height {
                height: 15px;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
            .font-14 {
                font-size: 12px;
            }

            .font-12 {
                font-size: 10px;
            }

            .font-10 {
                font-size: 8px;
            }

            .height-space {
                height: 7px;
            }

            .image {
                width: 350px;
            }

            .container {
                max-width: 350px;
            }

            .profile {
                max-width: 50px;
                max-height: 50px;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

</html>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="sc-gPEVay eQYmiW arial container"
    style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="sc-gPEVay eQYmiW arial"
                    style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                <span class="sc-kgAjT cuzzPp" style="margin-right: 15px; display: block;">
                                    <img src="https://paralympic.sk/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/AC4Q2271-scaled.jpg" role="presentation"
                                        class="sc-cHGsZl bHiaRe profile">
                                </span>

                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                <h3 color="#184784" class="sc-fBuWsC eeihxG blue font-14" style="margin: 0px;">
                                    <span>Tomáš</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>Valach</span>
                                </h3>
                                <p color="#000000" font-size="large" class="sc-fMiknA bxZCMx font-12"
                                    style="margin: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 22px;">
                                    <span><b>Motivátor</b></span>
                                </p>
                                <p color="#000000" font-size="large" class="sc-dVhcbM fghLuF font-12"
                                    style="margin: 0px; font-weight: 500; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 16px;">
                                    <span><span class="fa">Národný projekt </span><b> SME SI ROVNÍ</b></span>
                                </p>
                            </td>
                            <td width="20">
                                <div style="width: 20px;"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td color="#184784" direction="vertical" width="1" class="sc-jhAzac hmXDXQ blue"
                                style="width: 0px; border-bottom: none; border-left: 2px solid;"></td>
                            <td width="20">
                                <div style="width: 20px;"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="sc-gPEVay eQYmiW arial"
                                    style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium;">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr class="tr-height" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                            <td style="padding: 0px;">
                                                <p class="font-10 bold i-block blue" style="margin: 1px; padding-right: 4px;">
                                                    Mobil:
                                                </p><a href="tel:0914196212" color="#000000" class="sc-gipzik iyhjGb font-10 i-block"
                                                    style="text-decoration: underline; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><span>0914196212</span></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="tr-height" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                            <td class="font-12" style="padding: 0px;">
                                                <p class="font-10 bold i-block blue" style="margin: 1px; padding-right: 4px;">
                                                    E-mail:
                                                </p>
                                                <a href="mailto:tomas.valach@smesirovni.sk" color="#000000" class="sc-gipzik iyhjGb font-10"
                                                    style="text-decoration: underline; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><span>tomas.valach@smesirovni.sk</span></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="tr-height" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                            <td class="font-12" style="padding: 0px;">
                                                <p class="font-10 bold i-block blue" style="margin: 1px; padding-right: 4px;">
                                                    Web:
                                                </p>
                                                <a href="www.smesirovni.sk" color="#000000" class="sc-gipzik iyhjGb font-10"
                                                    style="text-decoration: underline; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><span>www.smesirovni.sk</span></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="sc-gPEVay eQYmiW arial"
                    style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; width: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="height-space"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td color="#184784" direction="horizontal" height="1" class="sc-jhAzac hmXDXQ"
                                style="width: 100%; border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(24, 71, 132); border-left: none; display: block;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="height-space"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="sc-gPEVay eQYmiW arial"
                    style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; width: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="vertical-align: top;"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="height-space">
                <p class="font-10" style="text-align: center; padding: 0 30px;">Tento projekt sa realizuje vďaka podpore z
                    Európskeho sociálneho
                    a Európskeho fondu
                    regionálneho rozvoja v
                    rámci Operačného programu Ľudské zdroje.</p>
                <p class="font-10" style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://www.employment.gov.sk/sk/esf/"
                        class="font-10">www.esf.gov.sk</a>, <a href="https://www.employment.gov.sk/sk/"
                        class="font-10">www.employment.gov.sk</a></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <img class="image" src="oplz.png" alt="" srcset="">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please learn how to [ask], and create a [mcve]? Thanks!

Comment: I wanted add full code because i dont know what is bad.

Comment: I see but try cutting out some unnecessary parts. Leave only the trouble parts. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

The `media` attribute is not supported. The fact is that Outlook uses Word for rendering HTML markup for message bodies. You can find all supported and unsupported HTML elements, attributes, and cascading style sheets properties in the following articles:

- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 2 of 2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338200(v=office.12))

Comment: There is an issue with the HTML. btw do you keep this in a snippet to copy paste always?

Answer (score -1):

You are closing off your HTML before starting your `table`. I have added a body tag as well and same(full) code is below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
            <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
            <o:AllowPNG/>
            <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
            </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
        </xml><![endif]-->
    <style media="screen" type="text/css">
        .arial {
            font-family: Arial;
        }

        .container {
            max-width: 650px;
        }

        .font-14 {
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .font-12 {
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        .font-10 {
            font-size: 10px;
        }

        .bold {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .i-block {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .blue {
            color: rgb(24, 71, 132);
        }

        .image {
            max-width: 600px;
            height: auto;
        }

        .profile {
            width: 90px;
            height: 90px;
            object-fit: cover;
            object-position: center top;
        }

        .fa {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .height-space {
            height: 20px;
        }

        .tr-height {
            height: 20px;
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
            .image {
                width: 450px;
            }

            .container {
                max-width: 450px;
            }

            .profile {
                max-width: 70px;
                max-height: 70px;
            }

            .fa {
                display: none;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
            .height-space {
                height: 10px;
            }

            .tr-height {
                height: 15px;
            }
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
            .font-14 {
                font-size: 12px;
            }

            .font-12 {
                font-size: 10px;
            }

            .font-10 {
                font-size: 8px;
            }

            .height-space {
                height: 7px;
            }

            .image {
                width: 350px;
            }

            .container {
                max-width: 350px;
            }

            .profile {
                max-width: 50px;
                max-height: 50px;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="sc-gPEVay eQYmiW arial container"
    style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="sc-gPEVay eQYmiW arial"
                    style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                <span class="sc-kgAjT cuzzPp" style="margin-right: 15px; display: block;">
                                    <img src="https://paralympic.sk/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/AC4Q2271-scaled.jpg" role="presentation"
                                        class="sc-cHGsZl bHiaRe profile">
                                </span>

                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                <h3 color="#184784" class="sc-fBuWsC eeihxG blue font-14" style="margin: 0px;">
                                    <span>Tomáš</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>Valach</span>
                                </h3>
                                <p color="#000000" font-size="large" class="sc-fMiknA bxZCMx font-12"
                                    style="margin: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 22px;">
                                    <span><b>Motivátor</b></span>
                                </p>
                                <p color="#000000" font-size="large" class="sc-dVhcbM fghLuF font-12"
                                    style="margin: 0px; font-weight: 500; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); line-height: 16px;">
                                    <span><span class="fa">Národný projekt </span><b> SME SI ROVNÍ</b></span>
                                </p>
                            </td>
                            <td width="20">
                                <div style="width: 20px;"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td color="#184784" direction="vertical" width="1" class="sc-jhAzac hmXDXQ blue"
                                style="width: 0px; border-bottom: none; border-left: 2px solid;"></td>
                            <td width="20">
                                <div style="width: 20px;"></div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="sc-gPEVay eQYmiW arial"
                                    style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium;">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr class="tr-height" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                            <td style="padding: 0px;">
                                                <p class="font-10 bold i-block blue" style="margin: 1px; padding-right: 4px;">
                                                    Mobil:
                                                </p><a href="tel:0914196212" color="#000000" class="sc-gipzik iyhjGb font-10 i-block"
                                                    style="text-decoration: underline; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><span>0914196212</span></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="tr-height" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                            <td class="font-12" style="padding: 0px;">
                                                <p class="font-10 bold i-block blue" style="margin: 1px; padding-right: 4px;">
                                                    E-mail:
                                                </p>
                                                <a href="mailto:tomas.valach@smesirovni.sk" color="#000000" class="sc-gipzik iyhjGb font-10"
                                                    style="text-decoration: underline; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><span>tomas.valach@smesirovni.sk</span></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr class="tr-height" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                                            <td class="font-12" style="padding: 0px;">
                                                <p class="font-10 bold i-block blue" style="margin: 1px; padding-right: 4px;">
                                                    Web:
                                                </p>
                                                <a href="www.smesirovni.sk" color="#000000" class="sc-gipzik iyhjGb font-10"
                                                    style="text-decoration: underline; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><span>www.smesirovni.sk</span></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="sc-gPEVay eQYmiW arial"
                    style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; width: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="height-space"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td color="#184784" direction="horizontal" height="1" class="sc-jhAzac hmXDXQ"
                                style="width: 100%; border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(24, 71, 132); border-left: none; display: block;"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="height-space"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="sc-gPEVay eQYmiW arial"
                    style="vertical-align: -webkit-baseline-middle; font-size: medium; width: 100%;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="vertical-align: top;"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="height-space">
                <p class="font-10" style="text-align: center; padding: 0 30px;">Tento projekt sa realizuje vďaka podpore z
                    Európskeho sociálneho
                    a Európskeho fondu
                    regionálneho rozvoja v
                    rámci Operačného programu Ľudské zdroje.</p>
                <p class="font-10" style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://www.employment.gov.sk/sk/esf/"
                        class="font-10">www.esf.gov.sk</a>, <a href="https://www.employment.gov.sk/sk/"
                        class="font-10">www.employment.gov.sk</a></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <img class="image" src="oplz.png" alt="" srcset="">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are elements not supported by Outlook.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev yes the media query isnt supported, that is why we email dev's have fall backs. If something is not supported, we code around it. Example if media query is no supported, we dont place code specific for Outlook in media query. Thanks for the down vote btw even if it answers the question?